# flatbuffers sample gives non-standard syntax errors on compile in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, flatbuffers

I have been trying to reproduce something even simpler than the C++ sample in: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/samples/sample_binary.cpp

But I am getting some compile errors in VS2017 on the lines

```
//auto pos = compare->pos;
//auto two = compare->deviceType;
//auto desc = compare->description;
```

If I comment them out, it compiles and runs. If not, then I get the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3867   'PNT::PseudoGPS::pos': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member   LinkWareMessageBus  d:\source\linkwaremessagebus\linkwaremessagebus.cpp 50  
Error   C3867   'PNT::PseudoGPS::deviceType': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    LinkWareMessageBus  d:\source\linkwaremessagebus\linkwaremessagebus.cpp 51  
Error   C3867   'PNT::PseudoGPS::description': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member   LinkWareMessageBus  d:\source\linkwaremessagebus\linkwaremessagebus.cpp 52
```

Here is the definition of my FBS object:

```
// Example IDL file for the PNT Schema
namespace PNT;
enum DeviceType:byte { IMU, VAN, GPS, MAGNAV, SOOP }
struct Vec3 {
  x:float;
  y:float;
  z:float;
}
table PseudoGPS {
  pos:Vec3; 
  deviceType:DeviceType = GPS;
  description: string;
}

root_type PseudoGPS;
```

And here is the code that creates the FB object and then tries to access things (I am just exploring at this point, the code is not done).

```
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder(1024);
auto position = PNT::Vec3(4.0, 5.0, 6.0);
auto description = builder.CreateString("Magnetic Postion");
auto msg = PNT::CreatePseudoGPS(builder, &position, PNT::DeviceType_MAGNAV, description);
builder.Finish(msg);
uint8_t *buf = builder.GetBufferPointer();
int size = builder.GetSize();

auto compare = PNT::GetPseudoGPS(buf);
auto pos = compare->pos;
auto two = compare->deviceType;
auto desc = compare->description;
```

Answer (score 1):

`compare->pos` refers to an accessor function, try appending `()`

Comment: @Aardapple    I should write this on my whiteboard "I will not ask stupid questions anymore, I will not ask stupid questions anymore" I feel so foolish. Thank you for not saying this, and thank you for your help.

Comment: @Dr.YSG haha.. well the error message was pretty cryptic.